# How a window drawn by glfw or sfml is different than opengl drawing?

Tags: user-interface, opengl, graphics, gpu

Every resource I can across mentions the following steps to do openGL programming:

- Create a window using sfml or glfw.
- Load openGL function pointers using GLAD.
- Make an openGL context and attach it to the window created and make it current.
- Setup viewport size for openGL.
- Start calling openGL functions to start drawing.

What is a windowing library?

How creating a blank window is different than running a openGL program? Blank window (or any GUI element like button, checkbox, text input area, etc) is also a GUI so it must be drawn by gpu using openGL or these are done by different subsystems?
Also the computers which don't have any gpu how they draw things to screen?